# What is this weird character?

Tags: text

some time ago i found this weird character that i can t put it here because it doesn't work but i have images of it. It looks like a space character in the begin but it isn't.
When i google it i get this [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4%E3%85%A4) and some random character in the search bar. Also i can't find it in the Unicode/ASCII library of characters

Does anyone what this character is and it's purpose?

[image: this here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Google search string, you have a long series of the character [U+3164](https://codepoints.net/U+3164), the "Hangul Filler." [Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul) is the Korean alphabet.